# sRGB picture shows very differently on photo editor vs. web (driving me crazy!)

Tags: color-spaces

The photo looks nice Affinity Photo, GIMP and Photoshop in my MacBook. I preview the photo also with Mac Preview, and it shows exactly the same.

But when seeing the picture in the browser, it shows differently. Especially some original "white" shows as grey. When using the color-picker tool it actually shows as non-white. But it is hard to see in the editing software but easy on the browser.

When I load the picture with a browser, or even create a simple html file to load the img and it shows completely different.

I am embedding sRGB, using JPEG, PNG, trying different profiles. I don't get it.

Anyone can help?

- In the photo editing software I can't barely see the "grey area". It shows as white.
- In the browser (Firefox, Chrome, and Safari) when loading the html file you can clearly see it as "grey".
- But when I load the image in the browser (vs. loading the html file), in Firefox, or Chrome I CANNOT see the grey area (the exception here is Safari).

Even when trying to copy / paste or screenshot, the colors change so I am not able to replicate it easy here.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a profile mismatch somewhere. Can you post one image to dropbox, etc, so we can see all the exif data [uploading here will strip it all.] Also, is your workflow calibrated, & what is your default profile in Photoshop set to?

Comment: How do the pictures look on other computers? On smartphones?

Comment: This would probably be much easier to debug if you could post the picture (or a small part of it exhibiting the issue), both the original and the "web" version.

Comment: Please share the original image (from cloud, not with imgur which processes the image further) for repro.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a colorspace issue, but just to rule out a couple of oddities: are you scaling in in the html? Does doing so  make a difference (if it's flat white I'd be very surprised, but if there's a pattern... and we haven't seen the photo). Do you see the effect in the simplest html file you can generate, just headers and one `img` tag in the body? (to absolutely eliminate the possibility of accidentally applying [css filters](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) via a style, and anything even stranger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as monitors are concerned, white is just a brighter version of gray, the same as black is a darker version of gray.

The browsers showing the white area as grey are displaying the image darker than the browsers and applications that show the same areas as white. Or, to look at it another way, the apps and browsers that show areas as white are displaying brighter than the browsers that show the same areas as gray.

If your color picker tool shows less than full saturation of [255,255,255], or very close to it with all channels at equal levels, for an area in the image that looks white on your monitor within the editing application, then your monitor is brighter than a properly calibrated monitor should be. You should check to be sure you're using the proper color profile within the application.

*NOTE: Do ***NOT*** use a monitor profile within your editing application! If you do then the monitor profile will be applied twice: once in the application and again when your GPU sends the signal to the monitor.*

Answer (score 3):

Proper color management dictates that a jpeg should be in sRGB with the color space tag embedded (with very few exceptions). Then even an unmanaged program (browser) that assumes sRGB will display the image correctly.

Try using PS's legacy "save for web" (file>export>save for web) and make sure *convert to sRGB* and *embed color profile* are selected. IMO those two check boxes make it the easiest way to correctly export a jpeg for the web.

You can also try changing the preview mode to *internet standard* (no color management) as I have done here... if you see a big shift when switching from the default monitor color to unmanaged then the chances are that you either have a bad monitor profile, or you are double managed somewhere.
Bad monitor profiles happen more often than you might think...

If none of that clarifies the issue then the problem must be in the website design/html code. Perhaps something like a dynamic resize stripping the image exif/color space tag or compressing/shifting colors.

[image]

Comment: Some background would be nice. Do yo know what's happening? (Likely the dedicated photo applications use a monitor profile or something while the browser is "naive" (but is it?), so how does your suggestion influence what's happening?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, proper color management dictates that a jpeg should be in sRGB with the color space tag embedded (with very few exceptions). Those two checkboxes just make it very easy/obvious that the image is saved/exported correctly. Then even an unmanaged program (browser) that *assumes* sRGB will display the image correctly.

Comment: Anything like that belongs in the answer ;-). Like, ok, a jpeg color apparently isn't an absolute color (but it's a point in an assumed or explicit color space). I'm certainly not the only one struggling with the interaction between programs, operating systems, file formats, device definitions and what not.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica; added...

Comment: If the color picker within the editing application is showing some of the "white" areas in the photos as less than white, but they are appearing as white *within the editing app*, then the problem isn't how it's being exported, the problem is with how something like [243,238,251] is being rendered as white *within the editing app*. In other words, the problem is non-white areas are displayed as white w/in the editing app - not that white areas are displayed as non-white in some browsers.

Comment: @MichaelC, by "non-white" I assume what was meant is less than pure 255/255/255; but not something significantly less... (240-245 is where I set whites for most images). Especially since opening the image with a browser looks the same as in the editing app; it's only when loaded via html that it appears grey. I do agree the issue is not likely to be the export, but it's good to make certain. And that's why I said to also try changing the preview mode to check/eliminate the monitor profile.

Comment: It's possible some of the browsers also have a monitor profile incorrectly set on the OP's machine.